# NullPointerException in the JavaFX ComboBox API

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a strange issue on one of my screens and I really don't even know where to look at.
I look for items in a database and display details of them in a separate Screen (not an actual screen, a container).

The strange part is that the program works perfectly well with most of the items, but in some cases, it never works. The stack trace doesn't really help me, as none of it belongs to my source code.

Dear fellows, do you have any idea or hint about this issue?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.getIndexOfComboBoxValueInItemsList(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:444)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.updateDisplayNode(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:392)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.getDisplayNode(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:229)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin.updateDisplayArea(ComboBoxBaseSkin.java:125)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin.computePrefHeight(ComboBoxBaseSkin.java:180)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:879)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1384)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.computePrefHeight(Control.java:804)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:879)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.prefHeight(Control.java:686)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:1599)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.getMaxAreaHeight(Region.java:1721)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeMaxPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:1689)
at javafx.scene.layout.HBox.computePrefHeight(HBox.java:394)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:879)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1384)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:1599)
at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.getAreaHeights(VBox.java:394)
at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computePrefHeight(VBox.java:373)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:879)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1384)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:1599)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.getMaxAreaHeight(Region.java:1721)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeMaxPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:1689)
at javafx.scene.layout.HBox.computePrefHeight(HBox.java:394)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:879)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1384)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:1599)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.getMaxAreaHeight(Region.java:1721)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeMaxPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:1693)
at javafx.scene.layout.StackPane.computePrefHeight(StackPane.java:320)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:879)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1384)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollPaneSkin.computeScrollNodeSize(ScrollPaneSkin.java:874)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollPaneSkin.layoutChildren(ScrollPaneSkin.java:753)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1018)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
at javafx.scene.Scene.layoutDirtyRoots(Scene.java:513)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:484)
at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3900(Scene.java:169)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2199)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:363)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:460)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$9.run(QuantumToolkit.java:329)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Have you tried logging items as you get them from the database to see what items it crashes on?

Comment: Yes I did, and I can't see any correlation between the items...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you called `ComboBox#setItems(null)` somewhere in your code. Find all `setItems()` calls and add debug output of the parameter provided to see if it happens to be null.

Also you can try to update to developers versions of FX 8, as `setItems(null)` was [prohibited](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25142) there. So you will get much more clear stack trace.

Comment: Indeed that was the good answer, in some rare cases, I set items with a null component.